# Angular Directives and dhtmlxcalendar with icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, dhtml

I transform FCKTAG to INPUT and attach dhtmlxcalendar. It works.
Directive works fine too.
But I need attach calendar to an input with an icon [Initialization of dhtmlxCalendar Doc](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxcalendar%3adhtmlxcalendar_init)

[Initialization of dhtmlxCalendar Doc](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxcalendar%3adhtmlxcalendar_init): I must put in

```
<span><img id="calendar_icon" src="path.gif" border="0"></span>
```

In Angular Directive I put

```
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="g" ></input>' + 
 '<span><img src="http://clans.worldoftanks.ru/media/' + 
 'clans/emblems/cl_582/2582/emblem_24x24.png" border="0"></span>',
```

It's error. I need one root tag. I choose DIV:

```
template: '<div>' + 
  '<input type="text" ng-model="g" ></input>' + 
  <span><img src="http://clans.worldoftanks.ru/media/' +
    'clans/emblems/cl_582/2582/emblem_24x24.png" border="0"></span>' + 
 '</div>',
```

Annnd... Calendar doesn't load. 
I haven't any idea why it.

[plunker without an icon](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Nu3lIbjuyT6llvSHakr?p=preview)

[plunker with an icon DOESN'T WORK](http://plnkr.co/edit/VFHa0nuwVNsbe0zhiVEg?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In your link function you are get the input element using element[0]. Once you wrap all of it in a div tag it is no longer element[0]. Trying substituting the following code.

```
 var input = element.find('input')[0];
 if (myCalendar == null) {
     myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(input);
 } else {
     myCalendar.attachObj({input:input, button: input});
 }
```

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xw5E6eMs6KX8T6zmqmwT?p=preview)

Comment: Yes. Good. But I need open Calendar when I click on image (not input)

Comment: And I lost dynamic. Now y app works only with INPUT [0]

Comment: I changed the code slightly on this new plunker. It now opens on icon click only. http://plnkr.co/edit/u6QkmxXbsERpl7hC1vzi?p=preview